# Unable to Use External Hard Drive (NTFS Formatted)

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

I installed Lubuntu 12.10 earlier today on an old machine I have lying around. I've never really used this variation of Ubuntu before and was hoping I could get some (straightforward) steps on how to fix my issue.

I have a 2TB external hard drive which has all my media files stored on it. It is NTFS formatted.

I have installed Plex Media Server on the machine - it's only true purpose to be honest - but Plex won't detect any of the files within the folders on the external hard drive.

I was told this is because of a permissions issue but I'm not quite clear on what I should type in terminal.

The external hard drive is called 'External' and my username on this machine is 'manu'.

Can someone help me understand how exactly to change the permissions on this hard drive please? I need to share the drive on my home network so the other computers can read/write to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Type this on a terminal:

```
gksu nautilus
```

¡¡¡WARNING!! be very cautious with this command its like super-god command.

It will open nautilus file manager, then go to the HDD and right click on the permissions tab and change the permissions; once done type:

```
exit
```

On the terminal and or close nautilus; remember to this please!.

This worked on a EXT4 drive for me.

Answer (score 0):

from a terminal , run `mount` and find the external hdd that way ,

then `chmod 777  /where/hdd/is/mounted` . If that does not work , unmount the device using `umount` ( then the mount point for the hdd ) followed by `sudo fsck -`r ( hdd mount point )